# Flutter ListView grouped

Tags: flutter, listview

How can I achieve something like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XShsq.png

So far I handle to get this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIs0d.png

But I dont know how to separate each container

this is my actual code

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle boldStyle = const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
    return BlocConsumer<AppCubit, AppState>(
      listener: (context, state) {},
      builder: (context, state) {
        List<PurchaseCategory> purchases =
            AppCubit.get(context).purchasesCategories;
        return Container(
          decoration: buildBoxDecoration(context),
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 20),
          child: GroupedListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            elements: purchases,
            groupBy: (PurchaseCategory purchase) => purchase.date,
            groupHeaderBuilder: (PurchaseCategory purchase) => Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        '${purchase.date}',
                        style: boldStyle,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Total: 400 \$',
                        style: boldStyle,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const Divider(
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, PurchaseCategory purchase) {
              return ListTile(
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                leading: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: purchase.categoryColor,
                  ),
                  child: Icon(purchase.categoryIcon),
                ),
                title: Text(
                  purchase.description,
                  style: boldStyle,
                ),
                subtitle: Text(purchase.categoryName),
                trailing: Text(
                  '\$ ${purchase.price}',
                  style: boldStyle,
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

I handle to grouped by dates but I would like to grouped in different containers as the first picture

Comment: check `MergeableMaterial` widget

Comment: can you provide an example of how to use this widget, please?